# Is there a public iOS Game Center Xml feed?

Tags: xml, ios, game-center, achievements, leaderboard

I would like to be able to read a user's achievements and a game's leaderboard from Game Center through an external application not necessarily on iOS. Is there a publicly available xml feed or a feed available to iOS developers? I'm not currently a registered iOS developer, but I hope to register soon.